# django test giving abnormal results

Tags: django, testing, django-queryset

I am getting weird results when testing for 2 different views. They are both list views. The first one should only show active orders(active=True), the second one only showing historic views (completed=True).
I am using postgresql as a database also. Issue is that both the view works perfectly fine in the browser, however when testing pytest raises an error saying that an order that shouldn't be listed, is listed.

The views are as follows:

```py
class OrderHistoryView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'orders/order_history.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        qs = Order.objects.filter(Q(buyer=user, completed=True)|Q(seller=user, completed=True))
        return qs


class OrderListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'orders/order_list_view.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        qs = Order.objects.filter(Q(buyer=user, active=True)|Q(seller=user, active=True))
        return qs
```

The tests are:

```py
class OrderHistoryViewTests(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUp(self):
        self.req = RequestFactory()
        self.user = mixer.blend('user.CustomUser', email='test@test.com', password='1234')
        self.user2 = mixer.blend('user.CustomUser')
        self.advert = mixer.blend('advert.Advert', author=self.user)
        self.offer = mixer.blend(
            'offer.Offer', advert=self.advert, author=self.user2, receiver=self.user, accepted=True)
        self.order = mixer.blend(
            'orders.Order', advert=self.advert, seller=self.user2, buyer=self.user, offer=self.offer,
            pending=True, completed=True, active=True, disputed=False, cancelled=False)
        self.order2 = mixer.blend('orders.Order', completed=False, buyer=self.user)

    def test_only_shows_completed(self):
        request = self.req.get('/')
        request.user = self.user

        resp = OrderHistoryView.as_view()(request)   
        self.assertContains(resp, self.order)
        self.assertNotContains(resp, order2)
```

The second test is exactly the same, it just tests that its only showing active orders

error message is :

```sh
FAILED orders/tests/test_views.py::OrderHistoryViewTests::test_only_shows_completed - AssertionError: 3 != 0 : Response should not contain '10'
FAILED orders/tests/test_views.py::OrderListViewTests::test_order_listing_showing_only_active - AssertionError: 2 != 0 : Response should not contain '15'
```

EDIT:
I have done some further investigation on this and have found that even that the first "self.assertContains(resp, self.order)" statement is failing also. However when i run test_views only this "self.assertContains(resp, self.order)" test passes, however when i run all the tests together it fails. I have noticed after commenting out 5 different views in the test_forms directory, when i run the tests they all pass. Issue is that there is nothing wrong with the 5 form tests, their is no mock statements on them and the tear down seems to be working.

I then put a print statement to see what queryset is actually showing up:

printing Order.objects.all() shows ", ]>" and when i print(self.order.completed) also comes up true. However the result of the test failing says :  "AssertionError: False is not true : Couldn't find '25' in response"
Even though 25 is clearly there and completed. The view code looks perfect also and the view is a very simple view. What could be causing this?

Also i have noticed if i run py.test i only need to comment out 3 of the form tests and it will all pass, however with manage.py test i have to comment out 5 form tests for it to pass.

I just used print(resp.context_data) to see what is actually in the response...

{'paginator': None, 'page_obj': None, 'is_paginated': False, 'object_list': ]>, 'order_list': ]>, 'view': }

From here we can see the order "25" is actually in the response, i printed the username also and it matches.

Comment: pls check your indentions, the `test_only_shows_completed` function is one level too deep?

Comment: Sorry thats my mistake when posting. No the indentation on the text editor is fine.